Book where the setting is both in the present and past
I read this book a while ago and can't remember much, so it is sloppy.
There's the main character, whose mom is a witch but has kept it a secret. Also, the main character's mom had erased her memory to forget a boy in her childhood. It is also revealed that the main character can drag people into her dreams. I remember a part where the main character was in a car with her boyfriend and they suddenly stopped because they thought they were about to run over someone. Turns out it was a person, lost and naked, but she didn't seem to notice. Later on, they encounter that same person again as she is looking for the main character's mom to have revenge. I also think the book cover was purple. The present version shows the main character's current life and the past version shows the main character's mom's life and the things she did, including connecting with a witch and setting her free.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be a bit more specific about when you read this?  Do you recall the cover of the book?

Hi, and thank you. I think I read it back in 2022, and I do not recall the cover of the book other than the color purple.

When you talk of the present and the past, are the characters time travelling or are we just getting flashbacks or dual story lines?

When talking of the present and the past, I meant to say flashbacks. However, every chapter would be divided by such. One chapter would be in the past, and the next would be in the present. I think it is more of a dual storyline, if that makes sense.
